# Facebook connect integration error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating facebook into my iPhone application. 
Single sign on method works when i sign in via safari. 
But after i install facebook app and click "Connect to Facebook", app taking me to Facebook app. And there is a error message on top
" is misconfigured for Facebook login. press okay to go back to the application without connecting it to facebook"

What might be the problem? 
Please advice, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is probably going to sound like two of the lamest potential fixes ever, but I just had this problem...

1. I went from using the previous version of Facebook iOS SDK to the newest one, and one of the few things changes I made was adding the FacebookAppID && 4*************7. So, I deleted the APP ID and tried again and it worked. I recommend you check the AppID and spelling of FacebookAPPID in your plist.
2. Do you have multiple versions of your App on your simulator or device? Delete the old one and it might fix it, it was kicking me over to an older version of my app, and trying to resign me into the app when I was already signed in.

Hope it works for you,

Eva